# How to access inputs from Textfields in NativeScript and save them to variables like you can with document.getElementByID

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

So I'm just trying to save values from textfields to variables javascript.
I'm seeing that I should do something like this from another post

```
var view = require("ui/core/view");
function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var textfield= view.getViewById(page, "textfieldID");
}
```

however, I do not really understand how exactly I should be using it.  where do I call pageloaded and what arguments?

Comment: While using Angular, you may not really do `document.getElementByID(...)`. Use ViewChild to access element from your template. If you just want to access the values, you may stick to ngModel like @coderman said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In nativescript angular,

We have to use two data biding for this.

in your `component.html` file :

```
<TextField
    hint="username" 
    [(ngModel)]='username'>
</TextField>
```

in your `component.ts` file declare the variable `username: string = '';`

the `[(ngModel)]` is used for two way data binding so you can access the value from your textfield.

but take a note that you have to import `NativeScriptFormsModule` in `import:[]` array of your module file in order to use two way data binding.